# How to use jquery in SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)?

Tags: jquery, svg

I have embedded SVG in my php file to show a map. I want to use jquery on It but I have no idea on how to link jquery in it. I hope someone has already done such thing. So please help on this issue.

Thanks

**EDIT**

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108480/svg-draggable-using-jquery-and-jquery-svg) I found some useful info on my question. still i need to know how to add some css or link on load event.

Comment: You **not need  jQuery** (now all modern browsers have [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), reduce, etc.), use [ES6+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript). So, for *SVG* and general *DOM+data* manipulation, what you really need is [**D3js**](https://c3js.org).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The jquery-svg library specifically aims to facilitate this: http://keith-wood.name/svg.html

If you wish to avoid using a library, then there are a few basic initial challenges and decisions which you need to consider.

First, you need to specify how you're embedding the SVG. SVG can be included in XHTML "inline" in most modern browsers. Second, and more commonly, you can embed the SVG document using an HTML embed or object tag.

If you use the first approach, then you can use an HTML script element in the host HTML document to import jQuery, and then your scripts in the HTML document should be able to access elements in the inline SVG document easily and in the way you would expect.

If, however, you're using the second approach, and embedding the SVG using an object or embed element, then you have a few more decisions to make. First, you need to decide whether the jQuery should be imported into

- the HTML embedding context, using an HTML script element using an HTML script element, or
- the SVG embedded context, using an SVG script element inside the SVG document.

If you use the latter approach, then you'll need to use an older version of jQuery (I think 1.3.2 should work), as the newer versions use feature detection, which breaks on SVG documents.

The more common approach is to import jQuery into the host HTML document, and retrieve the SVG node from the embedded context. You need to be careful with this approach, however, because the embedded SVG document loads asynchronously, and so an onload listener needs to be set on the object tag in order to retrieve the host element. For a complete description of how to retrieve the document element of the embedded SVG document from HTML, see this answer: [How to access SVG elements with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript/3379830#3379830)

Once you have the root documentElement of the embedded SVG document, then you'll need use it as a context node when you make queries with jQuery in the embedding HTML document. For example, you could do the following (untested, but should work):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SVG Illustrator Test</title> 
    <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var a = document.getElementById("alphasvg");

            //it's important to add an load event listener to the object, as it will load the svg doc asynchronously
            a.addEventListener("load",function(){
                var svgDoc = a.contentDocument; //get the inner DOM of alpha.svg
                var svgRoot  = svgDoc.documentElement;

                //now we can query stuff with jquery like this
                //note that we pass in the svgRoot as the context node!
                $("foo bar",svgRoot);
            },false);
        })
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <object data="alpha.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="alphasvg" width="100%" height="100%"></object>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1, I found keith-wood library and was useful to me. On [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108480/svg-draggable-using-jquery-and-jquery-svg) I found some useful info. There I have some problem to add jquery like .css on start event i need to add some fill on load event. Can you tell me how can i do?

Comment: I just want to drop by and say that jQuery SVG library is not being maintained anymore and conflicts with jQuery 1.8 (works fine on jQuery 1.7)

Comment: jQuery SVG was last updated two years after the Dec '12 comment, and claims to be compatible up through jQuery 1.11/2.1.

Comment: When your site is not enforcing use of jQuery (in nowadays all browsers have [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), reduce, etc.), **use pure Javascript** ([ES5+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript) syntax). So, for *SVG* and general *DOM+data* manipulation, what you really need is [**D3js**](https://c3js.org).

Comment: A side note: `a.contentDocument` will be `null` if HTML and SVG files are in `file://` protocol, it only works with `http://` and `https://`, I guess it's for security reasons

Answer (score 10):

SVG uses elements in the DOM ie.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="600">
    <desc>My SVG</desc>
    <defs>
       <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#ffffff" d="M100,100L100,100Z" style="fill-opacity:
        0.3; stroke-width: 1; stroke-linecap: round;" fill-opacity="0.3" 
        stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round">
</svg>
```

Accessing it and manipulating it can be done the same way jQuery manipulates any other Object in the DOM. ie.

```
$('svg path').remove(); //removes the path.
```

If you are looking for a javascript library to manipulate SVG elements, check out
[Raphael.js](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/).

Comment: This does not answer the original question because this method does not work if the svg object is embedded using an `embed` tag.

Comment: Still a useful answer for those doing research or just curious if this is possible

Comment: jQuery does not support camel cased attributes, of which there are multiple of in svg, such as `viewBox` https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11166