# image drag and drop issue using jqueryui

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

image of a complete circle pizza and it is cut into 1/12 of the complete pizza in 12 pieces manually----> sorry I am not able to upload my image.

I am doing drag and drop for the above images. I am having a issues. First in draggable, I am supposed to drag only the piece of the complete pizza based on the number of division(this is what I want to do). For this process I have cut complete pizza into 12 pieces and positioned them manually to look like a complete pizza. But the problem is since the image and/or div is in square or rectangle shape I can not differ one draggable piece from another please give me some solutions. please excuse my language if it's difficult to understand. Thanks for your effort in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQueryUI draggable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634029/jqueryui-draggable)

Comment: Posting the same question over and over again without doing any reserach or making an effort isn't likely to get help here. This isn't a coding service...

Answer (score -2):

Think what you need is HTML5 SVG.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html

draggable

[SVG draggable using JQuery and Jquery-svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108480/svg-draggable-using-jquery-and-jquery-svg)

background image

[Add a background image (.png) to a SVG circle shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496734/add-a-background-image-png-to-a-svg-circle-shape)

Comment: can be done without SVG, and this isn't really an answer, you're just forwarding him to other pages.